# Understanding for-in loops

Tags: swift

How to interpret for in loops in swift.

I read the code as

```
for score in individualscores (5 numbers total) 
if score (5) is greater than 4 
teamscore = 0 + 3

else 
teamscore = 0+1
```

Actual Swift code:

```
let individualScores = [75,43,103,87,12]

var teamScore  = 0

for score in individualScores {
    if score > 4 {
        teamScore += 3
    } else {
        teamScore += 1
    }
}
print(teamScore)
```

The result returns 15, but I expected 5. Can someone explain this code?

Comment: `score` is always `> 4`, so you always go through the `+= 3`. Have you tried debugging yourself?

Comment: Why did you expect 5? And what do you mean by *`score (5)`*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why did you expect 5? The code is working as expected. In a For-in loop, All the objects in the sequence (it can be an array, a dictionary, a range, a string etc) are iterated. Since all of them are greater than 4, your loop runs 5 time and teamscore is incremented by 3 in each iteration which gives you 15. For perspective, modify the code like this:

```
let individualScores = [75,43,103,87,12]

var teamScore  = 0

for score in individualScores {
    print("Currently the value in score is: \(score)")
    if score > 4 {
        teamScore += 3
    } else {
        teamScore += 1
    }
}
print(teamScore)
```

You will see the following print statements:

```
Currently the value in score is: 75
Currently the value in score is: 43
Currently the value in score is: 103
Currently the value in score is: 87
Currently the value in score is: 12
```

So first the loop doesn't keep a counter, it just uses the length of array. It knows it has to iterate on 5 items. The first item is 75, it is greater than 4 so team score is incremented by 3. Next item is 43, same case as 75. So on and forth. That's how you get 15.

Your confusion seems to be that `score` will have the index of each item so it will go 0,1,2,3,4. As none of those are greater than 4, the control will fall through in else condition and increment `teamscore` by 1. That is how you came to the conclusion that you must get 5 as a result in `teamscore`. A comparison between what you had in mind and how it works would be the following:

```
let individualScores = [75,43,103,87,12]

var teamScore  = 0
var indexScore = 0
for (index, score) in zip(individualScores.indices, individualScores) {
    print("Found \(score) at Index \(index)")

    //What you had in mind how it works
    if index > 4 {
        indexScore += 3
    } else {
        indexScore += 1
    }

    //How it actually works
    if score > 4 {
        teamScore += 3
    } else {
        teamScore += 1
    }
}
print("Team Score: \(teamScore)")
print("Index Score: \(indexScore)")
```

Now your print statements will be:

```
Found 75 at Index 0
Found 43 at Index 1
Found 103 at Index 2
Found 87 at Index 3
Found 12 at Index 4
Team Score: 15
Index Score: 5
```

And the Index Score would be 5, as you expected but the Team Score is 15.

That is because for-in was iterating over values of the sequences which are 75,43,103,87 and 12, not their indices.

Credits for improvements to iteration code: [Robb Mayoff](https://stackoverflow.com/users/77567/rob-mayoff) and [Alexander](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3141234/alexander)

Comment: `0...array.count-1` is an anti pattern. For one, it'll error out if `array` is empty. Use `0..<array.count` instead. But even that's bad in this case, because you constantly see people making mistaking and writing `0...array.count` causing out-of-bounds errors. Use `array.indices` if you need the indices, or `array.enumerated()` if you need both the indices and the elements.

Comment: `zip(array.indices(), array)` is safer than `array.enumerated()` for reasons explained in [the `enumerated` documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/anybidirectionalcollection/1689618-enumerated#).

Comment: @NSNoob see https://github.com/amomchilov/Blog/blob/master/Proper%20Array%20Iteration.md#for-i-in-0arraycount-1--

Answer (score 1):

Let's use the “substitution model of evaluation” to figure out what your loop does.

Here's the loop:

```
for score in individualScores {
    if score > 4 {
        teamScore += 3
    } else {
        teamScore += 1
    }
}
```

The meaning of `individualScores` here is the value we most recently assigned to the `individualScores` property. So we'll replace the mention of `individualScores` with the value of `individualScores`:

```
for score in [75,43,103,87,12] {
    if score > 4 {
        teamScore += 3
    } else {
        teamScore += 1
    }
}
```

The meaning of a for-in loop is to assign the first element of the sequence to the variable (so, set `score` to 75) and execute the loop body, then to assign the second element of the sequence to the variable (so, set `score` to 43) and execute the loop body, then to assign the third element of the sequence to the variable (so, set `score` to 103) and execute the loop body, and so on.

So, let's replace the for-in loop with its meaning:

```
do {
    let score = 75
    if score > 4 {
        teamScore += 3
    } else {
        teamScore += 1
    }
}
do {
    let score = 43
    if score > 4 {
        teamScore += 3
    } else {
        teamScore += 1
    }
}
do {
    let score = 103
    if score > 4 {
        teamScore += 3
    } else {
        teamScore += 1
    }
}
do {
    let score = 87
    if score > 4 {
        teamScore += 3
    } else {
        teamScore += 1
    }
}
do {
    let score = 12
    if score > 4 {
        teamScore += 3
    } else {
        teamScore += 1
    }
}
```

Now we can simplify the `if` statements by substituting in the values of `score` in each one:

```
do {
    if 75 > 4 {
        teamScore += 3
    } else {
        teamScore += 1
    }
}
do {
    if 43 > 4 {
        teamScore += 3
    } else {
        teamScore += 1
    }
}
do {
    if 103 > 4 {
        teamScore += 3
    } else {
        teamScore += 1
    }
}
do {
    if 87 > 4 {
        teamScore += 3
    } else {
        teamScore += 1
    }
}
do {
    if 12 > 4 {
        teamScore += 3
    } else {
        teamScore += 1
    }
}
```

We simplify further by evaluating the conditions:

```
do {
    if true {
        teamScore += 3
    } else {
        teamScore += 1
    }
}
do {
    if true {
        teamScore += 3
    } else {
        teamScore += 1
    }
}
do {
    if true {
        teamScore += 3
    } else {
        teamScore += 1
    }
}
do {
    if true {
        teamScore += 3
    } else {
        teamScore += 1
    }
}
do {
    if true {
        teamScore += 3
    } else {
        teamScore += 1
    }
}
```

Now that each `if`'s condition is a plain `true` or `false`, we can simplify a lot more by replacing each `if` statement with its consequent (the block before `else`) or its alternative (the block after `else`) depending on whether the condition is `true` or `false`.

```
do {
    teamScore += 3
}
do {
    teamScore += 3
}
do {
    teamScore += 3
}
do {
    teamScore += 3
}
do {
    teamScore += 3
}
```

Since we removed all of the `let` statements, there is no need for the `do` statements anymore, so we can simplify them away:

```
teamScore += 3
teamScore += 3
teamScore += 3
teamScore += 3
teamScore += 3
```

These five statements have the same meaning as this one statement:

```
teamScore += 15
```

Since `teamScore` was set to 0 at the start, it has the value 0 + 15 = 15 at the end.